# Recibir vs. recibir de

Tags: significado

Quisiera saber si existe alguna diferencia de significado entre "recibir" y "[recibir de](https://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vCodigo=35297)" en el siguiente párrafo. ¡Muchas gracias!

"El nombre de este tiempo (llamado en otras lenguas, por ejemplo en francés, definido) obedece a la intención de contraponerlo al «perfecto», el cual recibe del participio con que se forma un sentido de completo acabamiento."

Answer (score 1):

En términos generales no existe diferencia entre "recibir" y " recibir de ", lo único que pueden existir son omisiones aparentes.

En el verbo "**recibir**" se encuentra implícito aquella otra acción de "**entregar**". Si tú recibes algo es porque alguien te ha entregado ese algo. Por tanto, "recibir" siempre lleva implícita esta idea.

- **Recibir** (por parte de algo o alguien) - **Entregar** (por parte de algo o alguien).

Tu ejemplo;

"... el cual **recibe del participio** con que se forma un sentido de completo acabamiento."

En este caso "**recibe** **del** participio" / "del participio recibe". El participio será el que **entrega** algo a ese verbo al que se refiere el ejemplo, "**un sentido de completo acabamiento**".

**Otros ejemplos**;

- Los niños **reciben de** los abuelos chocolatinas, caramelos y otros chuches. (en este caso **recibir** y **de** se encuentran en la oración juntos).
  Los abuelos son los que entregan algo a los niños (chocolatinas, caramelos y chuches).
- Los niños **reciben** caramelos **de** sus abuelos (recibir de, hay casos en que se encuentran en la misma oración pero separados).
  Los abuelos son los que **entregan** en este caso, caramelos y los niños los reciben.
- **Recibió mal la crítica** ( aquí "**recibir de**", esta omitido, aunque se sobrentiende que la crítica fue emitida o **entregada** por alguien,
  **Recibió** mal la crítica (emitida **de** alguien, por parte **de** ellos).
- El Guadalquivir **recibe** las aguas **del** Guadalimar.
  El Guadalimar es el que **entrega** sus aguas al Guadalquivir.
- En Tauromaquia, en la "**suerte de recibir o matar**" "**el torero recibe al toro**".
  El torero **recibe** (con una manera determinada **de** estoquear) al toro.
  El toro mismo es el que se **entrega** al torero que es el que lo recibe
  aguardando al toro.
- **El abogado **recibió** la investidura y su título para ejercer la profesión.**
  El abogado recibió (**de** la Administración) la investidura y ...
  La Administración es la que **entrega** al abogado la investidura y el título

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus explicaciones otra vez !

Comment: ¡Gracias a ti! Lo importante es que poco a poco vayas avanzando en la compresión del idioma.

Comment: ¡Gracias ‍♂️ a la ayuda de Ustedes, mi nivel de castellano es mucho más mejor que antes!